# Bezier path drawing additional line

Tags: swift, uibutton, border, uibezierpath

I am using bezier path to add a rounded border on my UI Button.
I am always having an additional line that I don't want.

**Code Here**

```
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft,.topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: 2)).cgPath
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    // Add border
    let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    borderLayer.path = maskLayer.path // Reuse the Bezier path
    borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    borderLayer.lineWidth = 1
    borderLayer.frame = self.bounds
    self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
```

**ScreenShot**
[image: Screenshot]

Thank you guys!

Comment: Why don't you use borderWidth ?

Comment: I thought it does not support corner radius! thanks it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this code:

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
button.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
button.layer.masksToBounds
```